# need design help using private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, private-inheritance

I have a problem with the following situation: a library (CardReader) implements the ISO7816 protocol and communicates with a smart card (implemented by me).

I have to implement a proprietary protocol that use this library.

In CardReader there are the following classes APDURequest and APDUResponse. and the CardReader class implements all the functions to send and receive these messages.

```
class APDUResonse
{
public:   
    /* ctor, copy ctor, move ctor, copy =, and move = operators. */
    //...
    int statusWord() const { return ...; }
    int sw1() const { return ...; }
    int sw2() const { return ...; }   
};
```

On the other hand in my software I have a hierarchy independent implentare the messages to and from the smart card. This is the interface of base class:

```
enum class MessageResKind { /* ... */ };

class IMessageRes
{
public:
    virtual ~IMessageRes() {};
    virtual int statusWord() const = 0;
    virtual int sw1() const = 0;
    virtual int sw2() const = 0;
    virtual MessageResKind kind() const = 0;       
    virtual void print( std::ostream& ) = 0;
};
```

Now my doubt is how to derive specialized class... my first attempt was:

```
class ADMessageResATR : public IADMessageRes, private iso7816::APDUResponse
{
public:

    // import iso7816::APDUResponse ctor
    using iso7816::APDUResponse::APDUResponse;

    using iso7816::APDUResponse::sw1;
    using iso7816::APDUResponse::sw2;
    using iso7816::APDUResponse::statusWord;

    ADMessageResKind kind() const
    {
        return ADMessageResKind::ATR;
    }

    void print() const {}
};
```

But I've compile time error: unable to instantiate abstract class ADMessageResATR: statusWord, sw1 and sw2 abstract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to expose the interface and use the library implementation, can you do something like this:

```
class ADMessageResATR : public IADMessageRes, private iso7816::APDUResponse
{
public:

    int sw1() const {return iso7816::APDUResponse::sw1();}
...
};
```

Comment: I thought that importing iso7816::APDUResponse function was enought.

Comment: In this case does iso7816::APDUResponse destructor need to be virtual?